# Switch case firing automatically

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to do CRUD operations using OOP and AJAX and I am facing a peculiar problem. The `switch case statements`are firing automatically. I have a `main_class` which contains all the code for CRUD. And as I want to show a list of all categories in a separate page, I am facing a problem. An automatic blank entry to the database into categories table is being done.

`main_class.php`

```
class Main_class
{

     function __construct() 
     {
        include("db_connect.php");
        $this->db=new Db_Connect;
        $this->conn=$this->db->connect();

        $this->category_name=$_POST['cat_name'];
        $this->image_name=$_POST['image'];
     }

     public function category_add()
     {
         $x=$this->conn->query('Insert into categories (name) values '."('$this->category_name')");
         echo $x;
     }

     public function upload_image()
     {
        $this->image_name=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $this->image_tmp=$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
        $this->image_upload=time()."_".$this->image_name;
        move_uploaded_file($this->image_tmp,"product_images/".$this->image_upload);

         $x=$this->conn->query('Insert into images (name) values '."('$this->image_upload')");
         echo $x;
     }

     public function showData()
     {
       $this->result=$this->conn->query('select * from categories');
       return $this->result;
    }

     public function oop()
     {
         $this->conn->query('Insert into categories (name) values '."('oop')");
     }

}


$obj=new Main_class();
switch($_POST['submit'])
{
case isset($_POST['cat_name']):
    $obj->category_add();
    break;

case isset($_POST['img']): //File upload code with OOPS

    $obj->upload_image();
    break;

default:
     $obj->oop();//just to check

}
```

`category_add.php`

```
<h1>Category Add</h1>
 <form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="cat_name" placeholder="Add Category"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="category_add" id="sub">
 </form>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#sub').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                method:"POST",
                url:"main_class.php",
                data:$('form').serialize() + "&submit=submit&par2=2&par3=232"

            });

        });
    });  
    </script>
```

Now the problem starts to appear when I added another page wherein I am trying to show a list of all the categories. When I fire this page I get a whole lot of errors and a `category` gets added to the database. I have figured out that that is happening because the switch case is being fired automatically but I can't understand, when the values are not set, how is it possible for the switch case to fire. Moreover, when I try to add a category and an image one by one, it works perfectly fine. No interference happens at that point.

`category_show_all.php`

```
<?php
include('main_class.php');

$this->obj=new Main_class;
$this->result=$this->obj->showData();

while($this->row=$this->result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $this->row['name'];
}
```

Comment: You have a button named `submit` in the form, but you're still adding `&submit=submit` to the data?

Comment: Yes, because the value of submit is different and I want to send `submit` to the `main_class.php` for using the same in the switch case.

Comment: I still don't see why you're adding `&submit=submit` to the data. Also, you're not  using `switch/case` as it's intended to be used. Just go with `if/else` instead, since that's basically what you're doing.

Comment: If I don't send `submit`, how else should I execute the desired code? Could you plz suggest another way. I would appreciate that.

Comment: But you _are_ sending `submit` since you have `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="category_add" id="sub">`. That will send: `submit=category_add`. What you're sending now is: `cat_name=foo&submit=category_add&submit=submit&par2=2&par3=232`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson exactly, I am trying to validate both image and category insertion using `submit`. My point is, if we get a `submit` as value, control shifts down and then whichever case matches us, the same function gets fired.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I mean. You are sending `submit=category_add&submit=submit`. No need to add the second `submit=submit` since you _already have_ `submit=category_add`.

Comment: Actually I get your point, since I used `if/elseif`, I dont actually need the value of `submit`. Thanks for pointing that out but I am still unable to get why the switch case is being fired automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If `$_POST['submit']` is not set, or is set and `== 0` your switch will be attempting to match a value that is equivalent to `false` and if `$_POST['cat_name']` is also not set, the `isset` call will return `false`, which will then match the value of the switch expression. So the code to add a category will get called.

To work around this add an `if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 1)` around the switch statement.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Never thought about that. And what can be a way around this problem?

Comment: See my edit. You just need to test whether `$_POST['submit']` is actually set.

Comment: My recommendation would be to use `if/else` instead. That would make the code _way_ more clear, since it's basically what the OP is trying to do with the `switch/case`.

Comment: Just added `isset($_POST['submit'])`, but the switch case still is firing and a blank category is being added.

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe - Don't use `switch/case` for this...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Okay, I will use `if/else` but I fail to understand why is `switch` case getting fired when the value is not even set?

Comment: I forgot that you still need to check that `$_POST['submit']` was 1 as well as being set. See my new edit.

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe - Because you're using switch/case all wrong. Read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) about how it should be used.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson although unorthodox there isn't anything inherently wrong with how the switch is being used. See the accepted answer on the question that this was marked duplicate of..

Comment: Actually, I think that the OP simply want's to compare the value of submit (after comments under the original post) and the fact that `submit` does contain the name of the method that the OP calls. So I think it should be: `swich($_POST['submit']) { case 'category_add': ...; case 'upload_image': ...;  .... }`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson hadn't been following that thread. I think you're essentially right. My answer is still appropriate for the original question though! :)